# How to add/upload own vector file (Shape, KML, GeoJSON) to Openlayers and show it on a map

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping

I started working with Openlayers and web mapping. Therefore I use a Cartaro (a web mapping platform) based on Drupal. Because I'm not a programmer it is (at the moment) much easier for me to administrate OpenLayers with the graphical interface in Drupal/Cartaro. Now I would like to add the following feature and I think it is only possible with some programming effort in OpenLayers:

I would like to give users the chance to upload their own vector file (mostly Shapefile, KML or GeoJSON) and show it temporarily on the map.

Does anyone of you has an idea or an example how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shapefile with Openlayers  (converts to WKT) http://indicatrix.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/shapefiles-in-openlayers/

Answer (score 3):

As your not a programmer you will probably be better off investing your time in a hosted mapping platform that will allow you to configure everything via a graphical user interface.

Check out [MangoMap](http://www.mangomap.com) it will allow you to upload shapefiles and customise your map without writing any code. Disclaimer, I'm the CEO of ManogMap. If you have any questions or need any help getting set up, feel free to give me a ping - chris@mangomap.com